# How to update values in GridView c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 4 Buttons - Button 1, Button 2, Button 3, Button 4.
I have "Amount" in each buttons which is stored as variable.

Also I have a "textbox" (to enter amount to redeem from each button) and "Apply" button next to textbox.
I click Button 1 and I enter Rs.50 as amount to redeem from that button and it will stored in grideview as Button 1 = 50.

I then click Button 2 and enter 20Rs. amount to redeem and apply. It will be stored as Button 2 = 20.

When I again click Button 1 and and redeem amount for 10Rs, it is creating new row. it is not updating the existing row value.

it is updating something like this :
**Button 1** = 50          **Button 2** = 20                    **Button 1** = 10

What I want is
**Button 1** = 60            **Button 2** = 20

```
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(ButtonName, "$" + AmountRedeemed.ToString("F"));
```

I added the above code during "Apply" button click.

PS: the button generations are dynamic. What i m trying is, once I "Apply" that button amount, I am storing it in key value pair. I am checking if the applied button already exists and update that amount. If not create one. But I don't know how to update the result in grid view

Comment: Do you mind to show your codes?

Comment: Hi @CyrilleConMorales - I have added the below code line in "Apply" button click                                  this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(ButtonName, "$" + AmountRedeemed.ToString("F"));

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: `this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add` Are you surprised that this always adds a new row??

Answer (score 1):

Its difficiult to tell you exaclty what is wrong with your code but looks like, when you are clicking on buttons, you are adding a new row there.

So, instead of creating a new row check if any row is there and use the index of existing row.

```
Replace - GridView.Rows.Add();

Use - Gridview.Rows[Gridview.Rows.Count-1].Cells['Button1'].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Gridview.Rows[Gridview.Rows.Count-1].Cells['Button1'].Value)+10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Create A boolean variable to check if Button exist in Datagridview
something like

```
        var btnExistInDataGrid = false;
        var btnTextTocheck = "Button 1";//pass button Being You clicked
        var btnClickedValueTocheck = 10;//pass button value Being You clicked
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView.Rows)
        {
            if (btnTextTocheck == row.Cells[0].Value.ToString())
            {
                //You must Work on the Currency..Will Throw error
                row.Cells[1].Value =
                    Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[1].Value.ToString()) + btnClickedValueTocheck;
                btnExistInDataGrid = true;

            }
        }

        if (btnExistInDataGrid == false)
        {
            dataGridView.Rows.Add(btnClose.Text, "" + 50.ToString("F"));// i removed Currency
        }
```